# How to prove $|\sin x|\le |x|$ from $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Today one of my friend asked the following problem in class,

> Suppose that we know $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$. Then can we prove **geometrically** that $|\sin x|\le |x|$ for all sufficiently small $x$?

The professor told that it seems unlikely that such a proof exists because the **geometric** proof of the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$ uses the fact that $\cos x\le \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\le 1$ at some point.

After reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) I have found that there are other proofs of the limit which doesn't use the inequality just mentioned. I tried to prove the claim but couldn't. Is there really any proof of the problem at all?

---

For the definition of $\sin$-function assume the definition given in the section *Right-angled triangle definition* of [this page](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjADahUKEwjc9_vJq5zIAhVGkI4KHRicAVA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSine&usg=AFQjCNHG1xQ5ctj-h468Nel7CrPlZOQFAw).

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) / x = 1$ **alone** won't imply $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$ for sufficiently small $|x|$.

Comment: @user251257: What other things need to be assumed?

Comment: How do you define the function $\sin$?

Comment: @user37238: Already said in the post. Please read it fully before commenting.

Comment: You also have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+x^3}=1$ and you don't have $|x|\geq |x+x^3|$. In fact, $|x+x^3|=|x||1+x^2|\geq|x|$.

Comment: @yurnero: But in that case you don't have the properties of $\sin$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a unit circle. Draw a straight segment from the origin to a point $P$ on the edge of the circle at angle $x$ above the horizontal axis.  Add a segment from $P$ straight down to the horizontal axis.  The length of that segment is $|\sin(x)|$.  The length of the arc from $P$ to $(1,0)$ is $|x|$.  The arc is longer because the segment is the shortest possible path from P to the horizontal axis.  QED, $|x|\ge |\sin(x)|$

Comment: "The length of the arc from $P$ to $(1,0)$ is $|x|$"-why?

Comment: @user170039  If x is the angle in radians, then by definition of radians.  Radians = archlength / radius

Comment: @user170039  That's why I specified "the unit circle", because the radius is conveniently 1.

Comment: @user170039  How did I deduce which relation?  I didn't deduce the definition of radians, it's the definition.  If the angle is x radians, that means that the arclength / radius is x.

Answer (score 1):

For a geometric proof of $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ you don't even have to know that limit. Consider an arc of length $2x$ on the unit circle. If its endpoints are $A$ and $B$ then certainly $|AB|\leq 2x$. On the other hand, by the "right-angled triangle-definition" of $\sin$ one has $|AB|=2\sin x$.